# how can I Collaspe/Expand using Kendo menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

[what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVujo.png) I am a beginner in Kendo and I want to create button to collapse/expand menu item using kendo Menu mvc.
I don't want to collapse completely, just the written part and  let the icons shown.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
           .Name("menu")
           .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
           .Items(items =>
            {
  items.Add().ImageUrl(Url.Content("path_of_image")).Text("Collapse").HtmlAttributes( new {@onclick = "collapse()" });
          }))
<script>
        function collapse() {

//what should I do 
            }

        }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the PanelBar's `expand` and `collapse` methods.

Comment: thanks for reply ,I have edited my question ,how can I do it ?